# Redshift: milliseconds to timestamp

Tags: type-conversion, timestamp, amazon-redshift

Let us say we have have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tech_time(
    ms_since_epoch BIGINT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS readable_time(
    ts timestamp without time zone,
);
```

Let us say `tech_time` has data and we would like to populate `readable_time`.

So in Postgres you could use `to_timestamp(double precision)` and do something like

```
INSERT INTO readable_time(ts)
SELECT DISTINCT to_timestamp(ms_since_epoch::float / 1000) AS ts,
FROM tech_time;
```

No such function seems to exist in Amazon Redshift:

> function to_timestamp(double precision) does not exist

My question is: how do I properly populate `readable_time`, while losing the least amount of precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try using `DATEADD` and add the `ms_since_epoch` to January 1, 1970:

```
INSERT INTO readable_time (ts)
SELECT DATEADD(ms, ms_since_epoch, 'epoch')
FROM tech_time;
```